# Custom panel in Wordpress after login

Tags: wordpress

I have a table in my MySQL records with users of my site. Now I want to integrate this table with a Wordpress blog, allowing users to login and be directed to a custom panel.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'd say you should look into user roles and making your own plugin. It's pretty easy but definitely more involved than a simple answer on this forum.

Comment: Do not know much about programming. Can you tell me if there is already a similar plugin?

Comment: This might help: http://www.joshstauffer.com/wordpress-redirect-users-after-log-in/ though when you say "custom panel" I don't know what you mean. A specific panel already existing in the admin panel? Or like a custom panel where they administer their own blogs or something?

Comment: No, the custom panel I say is a simple page where are listed invoices paid and outstanding. To register on the blog you need to sign a paid plan. :)

Comment: Well, about all I can suggest is google searching "wordpress invoice plugin" cause there are quite a few invoice plugins. But if you have no programming experience you are either going to be limited to what's available or you will have to hire someone to build the plugin for you specific to your needs.